# Share data between pages in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a very basic class with a users Twitter token information. Every time I call the API I will be needing this class so I was wondering what the best way would be to share it between pages. The class is serialized the first time when the token is requested from twitter.

So what I could do is just deserialize it in every page if I don't have it yet. But is this a good way to go? Are there better ways than constantly needing to deserialize the class? (faster ways maybe, or ar there no performance issues with this at all?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a TwitterSettings.cs class in your project, and define the members as static.
So that you can set their values in the Main page and then access them throughout the application something like this,

```
oauthToken = TwitterSettings.AccessToken;
```

And one other way to achieve this is by using Application resources from App.xaml.cs page
Check this link for [Application Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa348545).

Comment: But the first step is always deserialization (when the app has just been launched): every user has a different token so at some point I have to set the members..